# Split String at position in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, split, position

I have a date stamp (020920111422) and I want to split it to

day = 02,
month = 09,
year = 2011,
hour = 14, 
and minute = 22

Is there a "split string at position" method in C#?

Comment: As said @Marc and @Henk, for this particular case you should use `DateTime` rather than `string` methods.

Comment: @psycho: only when a DateTime is to be the end result. Not always the case.

Comment: @Henk: I agree with that, but I think it's safer and easier to let DateTime parse a string which may not be valid, and then use `.Hour`, `.Minutes`, etc attributes from the result object to retrieve the values, instead of testing each invalid case "by hand".

Comment: Usually, yes. But sometimes you want to handle invalid dates, or have other uses for the parts.

Comment: In this case, I have to use String, B/C it's used in a CVS file between two systems.
But with the dateobject, I can use ToString. Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want:

```
string x = s.Substring(0, i), y = s.Substring(i);
```

(or maybe i-1/i+1 depending on your exact requirements).

However, you could also use `DateTime.ParseExact` to load it into a `DateTime` by telling it the explicit format:

```
var when = DateTime.ParseExact("020920111422", "ddMMyyyyHHmm",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Ah, you had that too, `ParseExact`, you beat me to it ;)

Comment: Nice .. And your right! It's a 24hour format, so I'll mark your as the answer :)

Answer (score 7):

you can do this via [`SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) - for example:

```
string myDay = mydatestamp.SubString (0,2);
```

OR create a [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
DateTime myDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact ( mydatestamp, "ddMMyyyyHHmm" , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering on question considering "split string at position" - you can leverage [String.Substring(Int32, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) method by calling multiple times with different offsets.

Also take a look at LINQ [Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) and [Skip()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) methods which allows provide count of elements to return as well.

Otherwise see examples which other guys are provided using `DateTime.ParseExact(),` I believe this is most correct way to convert string you've provided to `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use

```
 var d = DateTime.Parse(s, "ddMMyyyyHHmm");
```

if the end-goal is a DateTime.

Comment: Should probably be HH; hh is 12-hour format - I'm assuming this is 24.

Answer (score 2):

Instead you can convert the date stamp by using [`Datatime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) and can extract the day, month, year, hour and minute you want from that date stamp. Refer the following code part for `Datetime.ParseExact` converting.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(YourDate, "ddMMyyyyHHmm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

Comment: the `hh` is 12-hour format; if the string ends, say, `...2330` (11:30pm) it will error; should be `HH`.

Comment: Its ok @Marc, I dint given him the exact answer but an example, and the format of DateStamp is based on his requirement.

Answer (score 0):

For more usecase, maybe  this can help

```
string rawData = "LOAD:DETAIL     11.00.0023.02.201614:52:00NGD    ...";

var idx = 0;
Func<int, string> read = count =>
{
    var result = rawData.Substring(idx, count);//.Trim();
    idx += count;
    return result;
};

var type = read(16);
var version = read(8);
var date = read(18);
var site = read(8);
//...
```